# Importing dates to mysql by csv file problem

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I hope someone could give me a quick answer to my question, since i'm not very good in PHP & MySQL.

I want to import a CSV File which includes 2 dates: `1-5-2017` and `31-5-2018`.

When i import the csv trough mysql, the dates look like `0000-00-00`

My code:

```
while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT into employees (naam,functie,afdeling,contract,DID,DUD,manager,profiel)
                  values ('" . $column[0] . "','" . $column[1] . "','" . $column[2] . "','" . $column[3] . "','" . $column[4] . "', '" . $column[5] . "','" . $column[6] . "','" . $column[7] . "')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert);
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to format your date. I don't see any importing, only INSERT.

Comment: MySQL accepts Y-m-d date format so you need to convert CSV date format to MySQL date format then insert it into the database.

Comment: i tried the STR_TO_DATE(@date_conv, '%Y/%m/%d') method but it's not working either, think i'm doing something wrong

Comment: can you please mention your date column name so i can help you.

Comment: My table structure: Naam, personeelsnummer, manager, functie, afdeling, contract, DID, DUD, profiel. the dates need to be imported to DID and DUD

Comment: CSV column no which having date

Comment: And may be you give us one or two example lines of your csv?!

Comment: Rather than this
    STR_TO_DATE(@date_conv, '%Y/%m/%d')
Try this
    STR_TO_DATE(@date_conv, '%Y-%m-%d')
This should work.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't point out which column is the date field 
 in `naam,functie,afdeling,contract,DID,DUD,manager,profiel`
you can use the function `strtotime` and `date` to convert this date format

like below code

`$column[2] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($column[2]));`

for example

```
// this will print 2017-05-01
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1-5-2017'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to convert date format

```
  $date="1-5-2017";
  $convertedDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than this

```
STR_TO_DATE('15-06-2017', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Try this

```
STR_TO_DATE('15-06-2017', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

This should work.Sample Sql query is mentioned below.

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1',STR_TO_DATE('15-06-2017','%Y-%m-%d'))
```